# Batch file finding a substring in a string

Tags: string, function, batch-file, find, substring

I am trying to make a function which finds one character substring in an other string. I can't make it work. (SET "_gf=!_strif!:~!_cf!,1) line does not work.

Note: The function written below is the working corrected edition:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET "_stri=abcdefghij"
SET "_strf=c"
SET "_s=0"
CALL :instr %_stri%, %_strf%, %_s%
echo Found at %_result%. position >> fun.txt
goto :eof

:instr
SETLOCAL
SET "_strif=%1"
SET "_strff=%2"
SET "_sf=%3"
SET "_cf="
SET "_gf="
FOR /L %%a IN (%_sf%,1,10) DO (
    SET "_cf=%%a"
    SET "_gf=!_strif:~%%a,1!"
    IF "!_gf!"=="!_strff!" GOTO ENDF
)
:ENDF
ENDLOCAL & SET "_result=%_cf%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET "_gf=!_strif!:~!_cf!,1
         ^......^  ^...^    Variable start and end as seen by the parser
```

Better use

```
SET "_gf=!_strif:~%%a,1!"
```

Comment: Ok. That line works now. The "if" line also looks working. But function does not return something. The "_cf" variable has taken "2" (I checked it by ECHO after ":ENDF") but does not return.

Comment: @kitapmitap, of course, you have and `endlocal` that discards the changes to the variables and as `!_cf!` is using delayed expansion and is not accessed until the `set` is executed (not at parse time), there is no value in the variable. Use `ENDLOCAL & SET "_result=%_cf%"`. This way the variable is replaced with the value at parse time. Also, you should only change `_cf` when the character has been found.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works and returns the position. But I can still not understand the difference between the ! and %.

Comment: @kitapmitap when executing a batch file and a line or block of lines are reached`%var%` references are removed and replaced with the value inside the variable **before** execute the line. `!var!` means that the indicated replacement must be *delayed* until the moment the command using the variable is executed.